# GraphQL fields as a function

Tags: javascript, graphql, closures, graphql-js, hoisting

I am studying `GraphQL` and I get a bit confused from different implementations on the specific issue when writing the `fields` of a `GraphQLObjectType`.
What is the difference between these two implementations?

1.

```
var schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {  // as object
      echo: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        args: {
          email: { type: EmailType }
        },
        resolve: (root, {email}) => {
          return email;
        }
      }
    }
  })
});
```

2. 

```
var ComplicatedArgs = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'ComplicatedArgs',
  fields: () => ({ // as function
    complexArgField: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      args: {
        complexArg: { type: ComplexInput }
      },
    }
  }),
});
```

Comment: What difference in particular do you refer to? The first snippet creates a whole schema with a query type and a resolvable `echo` field, the second snippet only creates an object type with a `complexArgField` field and no resolver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you need to make a circular reference.

Look for my similiar answer here

[Dynamically creating graphql schema with circular references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256942/dynamically-creating-graphql-schema-with-circular-references/39290345#39290345)

Comment: So would you say it is a good practice to always use `fields` as a function?

Comment: Thats strongly opinioned, but in my opinion it is! It has no big harm on the performance

Answer (score 6):

This is a great example of CLOSURE. Imagine you have two types in a file and they are referencing each other.

```
const BookType= new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'BookType',
    fields: {  // as object
      author: {
        type: AuthorType,
        
        resolve: (parentValue, args) => {
          // query the author based on your db implementation.
        }
      } }
  })
```

BookType has a field author and referencing **AuthorType**. Now imagine you have AuthorType defined under "BookType" referencing **BookType**

```
const AuthorType= new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'AuthorType',
    fields: {  // as object
      books: {
        type: new GraphQLList(BookType), //one author might have multiple books
        
        resolve: (parentValue, args) => {
          // query the books based on your db implementation.
        }
      } }
  })
```

So when Javascript engine needs to use `BookType` it will see that `fields.author.type` is AuthorType and AuthorType is not defined above. So it will give

```
reference error:AuthorType is not defined
```

to circumvent this, we turn fields to a function. this function is a CLOSURE function. this is a great example why closures are so helpful.

When js engine reads the file first, it saves all the variables that are referenced inside of a function into memory heap as a closure storage of that function. All the variables that `BookType.fields` need are stored into the closure environment of the BookType.fields(). So now if javascript executes the Booktype.fields(), it checks if "AuthorType" is defined inside the function, it is not defined so it checks its closure storage, **AuthorType** was already stored there in the beginning, so it uses it.

Comment: great answer explaining JavaScript's hoisting behavior with closures.