# Does implementing graphql fields as functions, represent the usage of closure or hoisting behaviors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, closures, hoisting

I've been studying graphql recently and I found out to implement a circular reference inside my schema, I need to declare my field property as a `thunk` or a `function`, referring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579416/graphql-fields-as-a-function/62736260#62736260) it helped me a lot to understand this.

If I may quote from that answer,

> Imagine you have two types in a file and they are referencing each other.

```
const BookType= new GraphQLObjectType({ 
    name: 'BookType',
    fields: {  // as object -> not the correct implementation yet
      author: {
        type: AuthorType,
        
        resolve: (parentValue, args) => {
          // query the author based on your db implementation.
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

> `BookType` has a field author and referencing `AuthorType`. Now imagine you have `AuthorType` defined under `BookType` referencing `BookType`,

```
const AuthorType= new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'AuthorType',
    fields: {  // as object
      books: {
        type: new GraphQLList(BookType), //one author might have multiple books
        
        resolve: (parentValue, args) => {
          // query the books based on your db implementation.
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

> So when Javascript engine needs to use `BookType` it will see that `fields.author.type` is `AuthorType` and `AuthorType` is not defined above. So it will give `reference error:AuthorType is not defined`.

So the correct implementation of `BookType` would be,

```
const BookType= new GraphQLObjectType({ 
    name: 'BookType',
    fields: () => {  // as a thunk -> the correct implementation
      author: {
        type: AuthorType,

        resolve: (parentValue, args) => {
          // query the author based on your db implementation.
        }
      } 
    }
  });
```

What I need to know is defining the field property as a `thunk`, *for circular references or for references of its own type*, describes what usage of JavaScript.

Is it the hoisting or a closure or the both?

Comment: Yes, [it's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880419/1048572) [both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi can you explain why it is a usage of a closure. I see only the usage of hoisting ?

Comment: The `() => {…}` function closes over the free variable `AuthorType`.

Comment: @Bergi if there was no closures and only hoisting available in JavaScript, what would be the error

Comment: @Bergi if there is hoisting only `AuthorType` will be available to `BookType`. so closure is not needed there

Comment: If there were no [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572), calling the arrow function would complain about `Undeclared variable 'AuthorType'`, because it's neither a parameter nor defined inside the function.

Comment: @Bergi thanks man now I got it. Thank you very much